# Bulk Insert with match columns between table in SQL Server and csv file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I have a `.csv` file (coming from Excel), and I use a `BULK INSERT` script to insert it into my SQL Server table. The number of columns in the table is more than the number of columns in the `.csv` file.

Example : my table in SQL Server has 20 columns, I want to point the insert just for the 5 column that exist in my `.csv` file.

```
BULK INSERT [DbTest].[dbo].[Costumer]
FROM 'F:\DataCostumer2020.csv'
WITH
    (FIRSTROW = 0,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
     KEEPNULLS,
     TABLOCK)
```

Is there any method to specify columns in insert script that will match with csv file columns ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: When using `BULK INSERT` the definition of the 2 objects need to match. If they don't. you would have to `BULK INSERT` the table into a staging table, and the `INSERT` it into the final destination table.

Comment: Use the formatfile option or create a view that has the desired columns and insert into the view

Comment: Use a format file as @SMor recommends.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution, even when you have INSERT SQL statement with TOO MANY VALUE lines.
Bokningar.SQL (too long INSERT with 100K VALUES):

```
INSERT INTO Bokning (ID, PersonNr, RegNr, Datum, PassTyp, PassNr, PassInfo) 
VALUES
(936, '19590523-2233', 'ABC78Y', '2013-06-03', 'Forare', 0, ''),
(937, '19590523-2233', 'ABC78Y', '2013-06-04', 'Forare', 0, ''),
... 100000 more lines
(941, '19590523-2233', 'ABC78Y', '2013-06-12', 'Forare', 0, ''),
(944, '19590523-2233', 'ABC78Y', '2013-06-17', 'Forare', 0, '')
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE #Bokning(
  [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [PersonNr] [varchar](13) NOT NULL,
  [RegNr] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
  [Datum] [date] NOT NULL,
  [PassTyp] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
  [PassNr] [int] NOT NULL,
  [PassInfo] [varchar](50) NULL
)

DECLARE @Content NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Load the content from the file
SELECT @Content = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\Bokningar.SQL', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents;

WITH Raw_CTE AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS LineNumber,
        TRIM(value) AS SplitLine
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Content, CHAR(10))
),
NumberedLines_CTE AS (
    SELECT
        -- strip SQL "( ... )," mockup to make it CSV
        SUBSTRING(SplitLine, 2, LEN(SplitLine) - 4) AS SplitLine
    FROM Raw_CTE
    WHERE LineNumber > 2 AND LEN(SplitLine) > 10 -- skip no data lines
),
SplitLinesCTE AS (
    SELECT
        REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(value)), '''', '') AS ColumnValue,
        -- number of columns is 7
        FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) / 7) AS RowNum,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) % 7 AS ColNum
    FROM NumberedLines_CTE
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(SplitLine, ',')
)
-- Pivot the data and insert into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #Bokning 
SELECT
    [0] AS ID,
    [1] AS PersonNr,
    [2] AS RegNr,
    [3] AS Datum,
    [4] AS PassTyp,
    [5] AS PassNr,
    [6] AS PassInfo
FROM SplitLinesCTE
PIVOT (
    MAX(ColumnValue) FOR ColNum IN 
        ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) AS PivotTable;

SELECT * FROM #Bokning
```

result:

```
ID  PersonNr        RegNr   Datum       PassTyp PassNr  PassInfo
936 19590523-2233   ABC78Y  2013-06-03  Forare  0   
937 19590523-2233   ABC78Y  2013-06-04  Forare  0   
938 19590523-2233   ABC78Y  2013-06-05  Forare  0
```

NOTE: This method can be best when some manipulation of data is needed or add some default values or ommiting values from source.